# Having trouble extracting HTML form results to a text file. I have been trying for 2 hours but nothing has worked

Tags: javascript, html, css

Like I said in the title, I am trying to get my results from the form below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>
/* Struggling with this part */
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="color:#e6e8e8">Video Game Form</h1>
<form id="form" class="form">
  <div class = "form-control">
    <label>All Time Favorite Game:</label>
    <input name="allgame" id="allgame" type="text" placeholder="Enter your favorite game">
    <label>Favorite Free Game:</label>
    <select name="freegame" id ="freegame">
      <option>Select your favorite game</option>
      <option>Fortnite</option>
      <option>Apex Legends</option>
      <option>Call of Duty: Warzone</option>
      <option>Valorant</option>
      <option>Rocket League</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-control">
    <label>More games you may play
        <small>(Check all that apply)</small>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
            name="inp">Minecraft</input></label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
            name="inp">GTA 5</input></label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
            name="inp">Call Of Duty</input></label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
            name="inp">Fortnite</input></label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
            name="inp">Valorant</input></label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
            name="inp">League of Legends</input></label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
            name="inp">Rocket League</input></label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
            name="inp">Elden Ring</input></label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
            name="inp">Zelda</input></label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
            name="inp">Other...</input></label>
        </div>
  <button type="submit" value="button" class="neon-button">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It is a basic form I am working on learning web dev, however I am stuck here. If someone wouldnt mind helping me take the results and add it to a text file in the same directory as the HTML and CSS it would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `<script>` tag, you'll either need to [add an `action` for the form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) or [manually get the value of each `input` element when the `select` button is clicked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement). However, in order to write the result to a text file, you'll need something on the server-side. Client-side JS does not provide the utilities to write to server-side files, for this would be impossible to implement.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know I cant add the results for a text file, I will try to print them on screen instead. Can this the easily done without changing the structure of the code I currently have, or would I have to redo it to make it work?

Comment: @charwisc Very easily. You'll just need to add `id`s to all of the input elements or add an `action` to the form and add a new file that receives the form data.

Comment: I think I understand, but just to clarify: Do I need to add unique ID s to all of the inputs? Secondly, do you have any reference to how I can actualy implement the action -> new file system? Sorry for having little knowlage, im a beginner and this is my first form ever.

Comment: @charwisc You only need to do one of the above. Yes, if you go the ID route, you will need to give them all unique IDs - (valid) HTML requires that no two elements can share an ID. I believe if you create a new file for it, you'll also need to assign new IDs to everything, so I'd do the first if I were in your situation. I'm a bit rusty on web dev too - it's been a while.